# Axiomatic System and Proof

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

**Axiom 1: There are exactly three points.
Axiom 2: Every point is on at least two lines.
Axiom 3: Each line passes through at most two points.**

Here are the given axioms for the axiom system. It was asked why the proposition **There are exactly two lines** *cannot* be an additional axiom. I am confused since I cannot prove that this proposition is true so that when it is added, it will contradict the axiom system.

Comment: Suppose there were exactly two lines.  As each of our three points is on at least two lines we have that each of our three points is in fact on both of our two lines.  But, as each line passes through at most two of our points, this contradicts that the line passed through all three that we had determined earlier.

Comment: Is the point of the question to show why exactly two lines are *not* possible? If so, then you can't prove it true, because it's false. Given the axioms, there would be three lines. Or is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: @JakeBrown "*given the axioms, there would be* at least *three lines*" there could be more.  For instance plotting the points $(0,0),(1,1),(42,0)$ on "graphing paper"

Comment: @JMoravitz Good catch

Comment: @JakeBrown Yes I want to show why it is not possible. I cannot prove it but what I know for now is that should be at least three lines. I want to know how I can explain that **there are exactly two lines** is indeed false. Thank you for your response!

Comment: I understand it now. Thank you so much @JMoravitz!

Comment: Sorry, I have follow up clarification... would to clarify what you mean by _ this contradicts that the line passed through all three that we had determined earlier._ Apologies, I got confused again @JMoravitz

Comment: Supposing we have points $a,b,c$ and lines $L,M$, we learned that as each point was on at least two lines, we have that $a$ is on line $L$ and $a$ is on line $M$ as these are the only two available lines for $a$ to be on.  Similarly $b$ is on $L$ and $M$ and $c$ is on $L$ and $M$.  As such $L$ "*passes through*" each of $a,b,c$ since each of $a,b,c$ are on $L$.  However we are told that $L$ only passes through at most two points per axiom 3, so it simultaneously must pass through all three of $a,b,c$ but must also *not* pass through all of $a,b,c$ as that is too many, a contradiction.